# How to reset fields in form with stream transform and bloc

Tags: stream, flutter, rxdart, bloc

I have a screen where I want to validate the fields with stream transform. When data is validated, the submit button must be enabled. When I submit the form, I want to stay on the same screen and reset the data. The send button must be deactivated.

The validation process is working, but when I click on submitting the form reset process does not work.

[image: Validation test]

Below, the complete code.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TextField Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  ApplicationBloc _bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc = new ApplicationBloc();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {           
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('FieldText Test'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildName(_bloc),
          _buildEmail(_bloc),
          _buildSubmit(_bloc)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildName(ApplicationBloc _bloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _bloc.name,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          onChanged: _bloc.changeName,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Name",
            errorText: snapshot.error,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEmail(ApplicationBloc _bloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _bloc.email,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return TextField(
          onChanged: _bloc.changeEmail,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Email",
            errorText: snapshot.error,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSubmit(ApplicationBloc _bloc) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _bloc.submit,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return RaisedButton(
          onPressed: (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data)
              ? null
              : () => _bloc.submitForm(),
          child: Text('Submit!'),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class ApplicationBloc {
  BehaviorSubject<String> _nameController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  Observable<String> get name => _nameController.stream.transform(validateName);
  Function(String) get changeName => _nameController.sink.add;

  BehaviorSubject<String> _emailController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  Observable<String> get email =>
      _emailController.stream.transform(validateEmail);
  Function(String) get changeEmail => _emailController.sink.add;

  Observable<bool> get submit =>
      Observable.combineLatest2(name, email, (e, e1) => true);

  submitForm() {
    //Send to api and wait
    //Reset values
    _nameController.add(null);
    _emailController.add(null);
  }

  final validateName =
      StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(handleData: (name, sink) {
    if (name != null && name.length > 4) {
      sink.add(name);
    } else {
      sink.addError('Invalid Name!');
    }
  });

  final validateEmail =
      StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(handleData: (email, sink) {
    String p =
        r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$';

    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(p);
    if (email != null && email.length > 4 && regExp.hasMatch(email)) {
      sink.add(email);
    } else {
      sink.addError('Invalid email!');
    }
  });

  //dispose/close all the streams when we call dispose() method
  void dispose() {
    _nameController.close();
    _emailController.close();
  }
}
```

(Not in this code) I tried reset textfield with controllers, it work´s but the submit button remains enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because your TextField doesn’t listen stream of text value in StreamBuilder.
For example, your _bloc.changeName,  is a controller, can only post the action into stream, cannnot listen any values.